# How do i click an element using selenium from a long drop down list?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a element let's say a list of countries from a drop down list, but i'm able to click only first few countries using xpath, when i try to click the last country seems the click not working.Here is the code(it works for first few countries but i want to click the last country from the drop down list)
If someone help me that would be appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.example.com/dropdown')

##click accept cookies button
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="cookie-button-wrapper"]'))).click()

##time delay
time.sleep(20)

##click on specific country from the dropdown
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="tv-dropdown__button tv-dropdown-behavior__button tv-screener-market-select__button js-screener-market-button apply-common-tooltip common-tooltip-fixed"]'))).click()
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@data-market="argentina"]'))).click()
```

Comment: If it is the last country you want to click, you could probably use the selenium to click on the scroll bar if present in the drop down to the bottom post point and then select the element?

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Comment: @MosheSlavin can you please open the url

Comment: @SohanDas You need to put the relevant HTML into the question. While adding a URL is nice, page content can change without notice and this question will be of no value to future readers without it in the question. Especially since you edited out the actual URL from the question...

Comment: @JeffC i will add

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First try to scroll till element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-market='italy']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Then try to click on it, using the last part of your code:

```
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-market="italy"]'))).click()
```